# Fetch multiple value using SQL select query and store it in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a library management system. There are three table as below:

[image]

I made the following SQL query to fetch information about a certain book and show them in a alert box.

```
SELECT  title,no_of_copies
FROM    books
WHERE   (ID = 2)
```

I have the following visual basic code to store the return value of that query and alert them

```
Dim value = Me.BooksTableAdapter.fetchFromBooks()
MessageBox.Show(value)
```

But it only showing the title value. How can I store both of the values and access them whenever I want.

Comment: instead of selecting as two columns select it as a concat string ..`select title + '-' +no_of_copies.....`